# Centre data in table cell

Tags: tables

This is my table: [image]

I would like to have all the data centered in each cell, for example: the operating altitude and the mission radius from class II. Can anyone help me?

This is my code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\scalebox{0.95}{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    NATO Class & Category & Employment & Operating Altitude & Mission Radius\\
     & & & (ft) & (km)\\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Class III (> 600 kg)} & HALE*(fig.\ref{hawk}) & National & 65 000 & BLOS**\\
                                \cline{2-5}
                                  & MALE*** & National & 45 000 & BLOS\\
    \hline
    Class II & Tactical & Tactical & 10 000 & 200\\
    (150 kg - 600 kg) & & Formation & &\\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{Class I (< 150 kg)} & Small & Tact. Unit & 5000 & 50\\
                                        \cline{2-5}
                                        & Mini & Tact. Subunit & 3000 & 25\\
                                        \cline{2-5}
                                        & Micro(fig.\ref{hornet}) & Tact. Subunit & 200 & 5\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}}
\caption{UAV Classification}
\label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With small effort to make table nicer:

[image]

In table code are used macro `\makegapedcell` and for units package `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
\newlength\pcol
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\centering
    \setcellgapes{2pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \sisetup{range-phrase = --,
             group-four-digits}
    \settowidth\pcol{(150kg - 600kg)}
\begin{tabular}{|p{\pcol}|l|l|S[table-format=5.0]|S[table-format=3.0]|}
    \hline
NATO Class 
    &   Category 
        &   Employment 
            &   {\makecell{Operating\\ Altitude (ft)}}
                &   {\makecell{Mission\\ Radius (km)}}   \\
    \hline
\multirow{2.4}{=}{Class III\\ (\SI{> 600}{kg})} 
    & HALE* (fig.\ref{hawk})    
                & National              & 65 000    & {BLOS**}\\
    \cline{2-5}
    & MALE***   & National              & 45 000    & {BLOS}\\
    \hline
\makecell[l]{Class II\\ (\SIrange{150}{600}{kg})}
    & Tactical  & \makecell[l]{Tactical\\ Formation}    
                                        & 10 000    & 200\\
    \hline
\multirow{3.4}{=}{Class I\\ (\SI{< 150}{kg)}} 
    & Small     & Tactical Unit         & 5000      & 50\\
    \cline{2-5}
    & Mini      &Tactical Subunit       & 3000      & 25\\
    \cline{2-5}
    & Micro (fig.\ref{hornet}) 
                & Tactical Subunit      & 200       & 5\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{UAV Classification}
\label{tab:my_label}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With the help of `makecell`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    NATO Class & Category & Employment & Operating Altitude & Mission Radius\\
     & & & (ft) & (km)\\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Class III (> 600 kg)} & HALE*(fig.\ref{hawk}) & National & 65 000 & BLOS**\\
                                \cline{2-5}
                                  & MALE*** & National & 45 000 & BLOS\\
    \hline
    \makecell{Class II\\ (150 kg - 600 kg)}& Tactical & \makecell{Tactical\\ Formation} & 10 000 & 200\\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{Class I (< 150 kg)} & Small & Tact. Unit & 5000 & 50\\
                                        \cline{2-5}
                                        & Mini & Tact. Subunit & 3000 & 25\\
                                        \cline{2-5}
                                        & Micro(fig.\ref{hornet}) & Tact. Subunit & 200 & 5\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{UAV Classification}
\label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Please note that I have also removed the `scalebox` since this will lead to inconsistent font sizes throughout your document. If your table exceeds the textwidth, you could change the font size to small, decrease the value of tabcolsep and/or introduce linebreaks in the column headers.

Comment: Perhaps adding some `\extrarowheight`?

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there any way of only changing the font size on the table?

Comment: `\begin{table}
\centering\small` changes teh font size of the whole table to small.